# Can a Uniquely permissioned List accessed via REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list which has unique permissions (inheritance is broken).

The user only have **contribute permission** to this list and don't have any other rights at Site/Web Level. When I **can access the list using AllItems.aspx** view it is accessible, but when the same list is access using the REST API (`/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('listname')`) I am getting the following output:

> "-2147024891,
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessExceptionAccess denied. You do not have permission to perform
>   this action or access this resource."

**Question:** Do we have any restriction when it come to accessing list via **REST API** if the List has unique permissions?